# C++ regex capture is dropping last char in email validator

Tags: c++, regex-group

C++ Shell Online Execution Link: http://cpp.sh/5z2uq

I am writing a regex to validate an email ID which **can have multiple dots and plus characters** in its local name and can only have one dot in the domain name.

The problem I'm facing now is in capture group. My domain name capture, i.e. group #2 is working as expected, as seen in the output.
But, when I try to capture local name i.e. group #1,

**it is not supposed to capture anything past the '+' sign not including '+'**, and after capturing local name, **output has a missing last character.**

Please take a look at my C++ regex code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    vector<string> emails = {
            "local@domain.com",
            "local.constant@domain.com",
            "local+addon@domain.com",
            "local.constant+addon@domain.com",
            "local@domain.c.o.m"
        };

    for(auto ele : emails)
    {
        str = ele;
        
        regex e("([\\w+\\.]+)\\+*[\\+\\w]+\\@([\\w]+\\.[\\w]+)$");
        smatch parts;
        bool match = regex_match(str,parts,e);
        
        if(match==true)
        {
            cout << "Local  : " << parts.str(1) << endl;
            cout << "Domain : " << parts.str(2) << endl;
            cout << "Valid Email ID: " << ele << endl << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Email ID: " << ele << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>
> Local  : **loca** 
>  Domain : domain.com 
>  Valid Email ID:
> local@domain.com
>
> Local  : **local.constan** 
>  Domain : domain.com 
>  Valid Email
> ID: local.constant@domain.com
>
> Local  : **local+addo** 
>  Domain : domain.com 
>  Valid Email ID:
> local+addon@domain.com
>
> Local  : **local.constant+addo** 
>  Domain : domain.com 
>  Valid
> Email ID: local.constant+addon@domain.com
>
> Invalid Email ID: local@domain.c.o.m

Notice how, in the local variable, my regex group capture is dropping the last character.

Questions:

1. How do I group capture till the '+' sign
2. How do I make the group capture not drop the last character?

Comment: So for "local+addon@domain.com" you want the local part to be just "local" and not capture the + sign or anything after it.

Comment: correct, not to capture the + sign and anything after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
"([\\w.]+)(?:\\+[\\w]+)*\\@([\\w]+\\.[\\w]+)$"
```

The first part `([\\w.]+)` matches the Local part (i.e. any word character or dot)
The second part `(?:\\+[\\w]+)*` denotes a non-capturing group repeated 0 or more times (matching a plus sign folowed by one or more word characters).
The third part `\\@` matches the @ character.
The last part `([\\w]+\\.[\\w]+)` matches the Domain part (i.e. two words separated with one dot), which you got right.

Comment: i can't believe i did not know about (?:) non-capturing regex group until now. Thank you so much for explaining in detail

Comment: if its a match, is there a way to capture only the local part without the dots?

Comment: use [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to make it more readable: `R"r(([\w.]+)(?:\+[\w]+)*\@([\w]+\.[\w]+)$)r"`

Comment: is there a way to capture group 1 by dropping all the dots in the same regex?